# How does "foo(*a)" work in Python?

Tags: python, function, arguments

Just switched from C++ to Python, and found that sometimes it is a little hard to understand ideas behind Python.

I guess, a variable is a reference to the real object.  For example, a=(1,2,5) meaning a -> (1,2,5), so if b=a, then b and a are 2 references pointing to the same (1,2,5). It is a little like pointers in C/C++.

If I have:

```
def foo(a,b,c):
  print a,b,c

a=(1,3,5)
foo(*a)
```

What does `*` mean here?

Looks like it expands tuple a to a[0], a[1] and a[2]. But why `print(*a)` is not working while `print(a[0],a[1],a[2])` works fine?

Comment: `*` means different things, depending on which context it is used. It can also be applied to a method parameter (not argument) or be used as a binary operator - make sure to be specific in titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to already understand that the asterisk is for [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). So the only confusion is about the `print` statement itself.

In python 3, `print(*a)` works fine:

```
>>> a=(1,3,5)
>>> print(*a)
1 3 5
```

In Python 2, however, it does not:

```
>>> a=(1,3,5)
>>> print(*a)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(*a)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is because `print` is not a function in Python 2, so Python 2 does not interpret the asterisk as argument unpacking instructions. In fact, `print` in Python 2 does not require parentheses. Wrapping a value with parentheses doesn't mean anything. `(a)` and `a` are the same. (Whereas `(a,)` is a tuple with one member.) So `print (a)` and `print a` are also the same.

You can, however, override the `print` statement with a `print` function [from the future](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html):

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print(*a)
1 3 5
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Actually in Python 2, `print(a)` works, makes it looks like a function..

Comment: Yes, because `(val)` is equivalent to `val`. (Whereas `(val,)` is a tuple with one member.)

Comment: Totally out of my understanding as a C++ programmer ;)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work in Python 2 because there, `print` is not a *function*. It is a statement.

But, in Python 3, it will work as expected, because `print` is a *function*.